# Winform running on Parallels with SQLite

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

Recently I moved some of my winform app data to SQLite. The app runs fine on all windows machines but Parallels on mac I am getting unable to open database file error. I can create the db file without any issues. But as soon as I check table exists I get the above error.

This file creation step works fine

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(dbFile);
```

But new connection step is failing.

```
SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=mydb.db3;Version=3;");
```

Error Stack

System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, SQLiteConnectionFlags connectionFlags, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum openFlags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open()
   at App.clsSQLiteDB.CheckTableExists(String table)

Comment: You didn't post the error message.

Comment: Does the exception you're getting have an `InnerException`, if so, can you post the exception type and message from that as well? And have you checked what the default directory that class will use if you're not specifying?

Comment: I don't have access to a mac. I am providing a full path to the database. Same path string as the create database file path string. Is this something with the linux path format used by mac causing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. Have to set the ParseViaFramework parameter true in the connection string.

```
SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=mydb.db3;Version=3;", true);
```